# How do I prevent access to my Jetty server from unwanted URLs

Tags: jetty

How do I prevent access to my Jetty server from unwanted URLs

```
10.34.6.67 - - [20/Jan/2015:13:04:05 +0000] "GET /pulse?authon&user=BB493827B64FD8B696FD0B600FA05429&url_heartbeat=1,0,156,156,0&db_conn=1,0,0,0,0 HTTP/1.1" 404 283
```

Comment: IMHO its Not possible as it would be jetty who would recognize whether the url is valid or not.. resource is defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if a requested URL is valid or not, the connection still needs to occur, and the request still needs to be sent.

The access log line you pasted shows that Jetty returned 404 (not found) for it.

Looks like it did the job with no further effort on your part.